# A-Frame: I am having trouble creating a button that displays a number on a plane

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I am a beginner with A-frame trying to create a simple calculator inside and having trouble making the number keys into buttons that when pressed will display the number pressed to the display screen. Below is my code snippet from html and from js. html includes the display screen and the "number one" button. js includes the javascript code that will show populate the number on the screen.

```
//a frame   
<a-scene>
      <a-entity id ="display" position="0 2 -5" geometry="primitive: plane; height: 2; width: 5" material="color: teal"></a-entity>

      <a-entity id = "NumberOne" position = "-2 0.5 -5" geometry = "primitive: plane; height: 1; width: 1" material = "color:black" text="color: white; align: center; value: 1; width: 5"></a-entity>

    </a-scene>
//script
document.querySelector("#NumberOne").addEventListener('click', () => {
  display.innerHTML += 1;
});
```

Comment: Great [MVCE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you've got here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, A-Frame build a 3D scene, and text is a mesh object, you can't change the inner HTML of HTML element. `text` you use is a component in A-Frame. it has some properties, e.g. font, value. you should update these attributes to change the element.

First. I register a new component to add an event listener on HTML element `click` event. when you click the `NumberOne` element, I get the value of this element text component. and add it to `display` text component value. then, update the text component with `setAttribute()`.

Here is my script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Add and display number</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Add and display number with A-Frame">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aframe/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script> 
    
  </head>
  <body>
<script>
 AFRAME.registerComponent('add-number', {
    init: function () {
     this.display = document.querySelector("#display");
     this.el.addEventListener("click",this.onClick.bind(this));
    },
    onClick:function()
    {
      var num = parseInt(this.el.components.text.data.value);
      var displayValue = parseInt(this.display.components.text.data.value);
      var sum = displayValue+num;
      this.display.setAttribute("text","value",sum.toString());
    }
  });
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity camera  look-controls
            position="0 1.764 0">
    <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500" position="0 0 -1"
              geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03;" material="color: #CCC; shader: flat;">
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <a-entity id ="display" position="0 2 -5" geometry="primitive: plane; height: 2; width: 5" material="color: teal" text="color: white; align: center; value: 1; width: 5"></a-entity>

  <a-entity id = "NumberOne" position = "-2 0.5 -5" geometry = "primitive: plane; height: 1; width: 1" material = "color:black" text="color: white; align: center; value: 1; width: 5" add-number></a-entity>

  <a-entity id="box" cursor-listener geometry="primitive: box" material="color: blue" position="-2 2.2 -1.5"></a-entity>

  <!-- Lighting -->
  <a-light type="ambient" color="#fff"></a-light>
</a-scene>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Big thanks Craig, a lot of this is new to me, but I can make some sense out of it. My only question right now is where in the <script> is the "NumberOne" entity being clicked on? In other words, where in the code is the function that responds to the clicking of the button? To me, right now it looks like you have the addEventListener on the display.

Comment: You may need to know A-Frame entity-component-system, in a short word, the entity like blank contour, and you can attach components to the entity, for example, wheel and engine to make it like a car. 
I register a component, and in the `init` function, I add click event listener, so every entity attaches this component would have a `clicklistener`. and in `OnClick` I handle this event, then I attach this component to your `NumberOne` entity.